# Is it a good idea to save nokogiri (or any internal) object to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, blob, nokogiri

My webapp on rails stores some model object's parameters in XML string, so whenever I need some info about particular object I have to parse its XML string. The length of the XML rarely goes above 100 lines. but due to desire of mine to optimize I wonder if I can store parsed XML as Nokogiri's object in db. Is it a good idea?

Comment: Why not rework your database schema so that you're not storing XML at all? I doubt Nokogiri documents are serializable in any sane way except by converting them back to XML.

Comment: I hate to think of the impact this causes on the runtime of the code. If you are trying to save memory, you're doing so at the cost of speed. Instead, buy more RAM and keep the objects in memory where they belong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there are probably exceptions, in general, you should avoid storing [marshalled objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html) directly in your database unless you have a **very** good reason. In the case of Nokogiri, as @mu-is-too-short [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417682/is-it-a-good-idea-to-save-nokogiri-or-any-internal-object-to-database#comment25296019_17417682), Nokogiri and Marshal don't play well together:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(some_html)    
Marshal.dump doc
# => TypeError: no _dump_data is defined for class Nokogiri::HTML::Document
```

That said, [Marshal#load](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-load) and [Marshal#dump](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) are part of the core Ruby library and are quite fun to play with. Along [with the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html), here is a quick code example showing how Marshal works, including a very basic benchmark comparing `Marshal.load` to `Class.new`:

```
require 'benchmark'

data_string = <<-DATA
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
DATA

class Example
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end

example = Example.new(data_string)

dumped = Marshal.dump example
loaded = Marshal.load dumped

puts "String Bytesize: #{data_string.bytesize} vs. Dump Bytesize: #{dumped.bytesize}"
puts "Marshalled object is larger by #{dumped.bytesize - data_string.bytesize} bytes"

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("Marshal.load: ")  { Marshal.load(dumped).data }
  x.report(" Example.new: ")  { Example.new(data_string).data }
end
```

Comment: thank you all guys! Your help is priceless: for my employer especially )